# Eclipse JUnit view is not shown

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-oxygen

I managed it to come to a state where *Window* → *Show View* → *Other...* → *Java* → *JUnit* does simply nothing in my *Java EE* perspective. It behaves as if it's already shown but it isn't (at least not visible to me).

The *JUnit* view is shown in the *Debug* perspective as normal.

`eclipse.exe -clean` doesn't help.

I'd like to avoid resetting the perspective (and, hence, didn't try that, yet).

#### UPDATE

The same happened with the *Package Explorer* view right now (a day later). I tried to restore it from the status bar and this time a bug report popup appeared: *Widget is disposed.* It's invisible now, it's not shown as minimized any longer and it cannot be activated via  *Window* → *Show View* → *Other...* → *Java* → *Package Explorer*.

Comment: Please check your right sidebar to see if it's been accidentally minimized after it was accidentally shifted to the bottom bar , i.e. beside the console & error windows.

Comment: With _Window > Perspective > Save Perspective As..._ you can save current perspective, so you can switch to the default perspective and reset it. After opening a view via _Window > Show View > ..._ the focus is set to the view and maybe you will see it by opening the view menu via Ctrl+F10.

Comment: @howlger I copied the perspective to _Java EE Save_, reset it (apparently this doesn't work, too, my customized views stay all there), still the same behaviour there. I opened the perspective _Java EE (default)_ and now _Show View_ → _JUnit_ works there without resetting but all my customized views are gone (I wanted to avoid this.). However if you make this an answer I'm going to accept it unless no other solution comes up.

Comment: In the workspace in the file `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` (which is used to persisit the layout) is there an `<children>` element with `elementId="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.ResultView"`? If yes, which IDs do the sibling elements have?

Comment: @howlger There are 3 such elements. None of them has a sibling with an ID (they have parents and two have also grandparents named `<children>` with `xmi:id`s) and they have 3 different `xmi:id`s.

Comment: Does one have a grandparent `<windows>`? If yes, the view is detached and might be shown outside of the screen (check the `x` and `y` attributes for that).

Comment: @howlger Yes. But `x="1950" y="44"` should be OK for my dual monitor setup. Closing Eclipse, setting the `x/y` values to `"0"` and starting Eclipse doesn't help either.

Comment: And what's about `width` and `height`? Both should be > 0. Make a backup of `workbench.xmi` and try to delete the `<windows>` element with its content. Maybe your dual monitor setup does not like detached views/editors.

Comment: @howlger All are > 0. Dual monitor setup and detaching worked here for months and for years at other places.

Comment: Was it always like it is now ? If not, what was done that may have changed it ?

Comment: @Trunk It wasn't until Friday. When starting Eclipse today this behaviour suddenly appeared without doing anything special.

Comment: You have Eclipse auto-updating every time it's opened ? If so, check details of recent update to Photon.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Maybe here ?]

Try the right sidebar - it may have got here through accidental clicking !

Comment: If it'd that easy I wouldn't have asked on SO.